# git install : password authentication failure

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to install git by refering to this link :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q69YaOjqNhg

Upon running 'sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure' I am getting authentication error for execute[migrate database].

Please see the attached screen shot of the error.

I am not sure when and where did the password got created. How can I reset or find the password? [image]

thank you

Comment: I'm not sure if you made a typo or not so I'll just ask to be sure: are you trying to install just git or gitlab? You said you are trying to install git, but the error refers to gitlab. If you just want to install git you don't need to follow all those steps, you only have to run:
    sudo apt-get install git

Comment: My bad. I meant to install gitlab

Answer (score 0):

I followed another tutorial that uses git to access gitlab remotely and it worked.

Here is the link to the one that worked:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7p0hrpNaJ14